# Python count program wont work as expected

Tags: python, python-3.x

im new to python and i have a count program that i dont know whats wrong with, for some reason, when trying to run it, when i put in Y or N for slow count, it just does nothing and exits with code 0.

Heres my code:

```
def cnt(start, end):
    for x in range(start, end+1):
        print(x)
        time.sleep(1)
    print("Done!")

def count():
    num = int(input("Enter a number to count to: "))
    #Slow count meaning counting 1 by 1 in console.
    slcnt = bool(input("Would you like to slow count? Y/N: "))
    if slcnt == "Y":
        cnt(0, num)
    elif slcnt == "N":
        for i in range(num):
            print(i)
        print("Done")
            
count()
```

Comment: `slcnt` is a boolean (because you made it so). A boolean can't be equal to `"Y"` or `"N"`, which are both strings. Get rid of the `bool()` around the `input(...)`

Comment: Thanks for the reply, i just thought the bool was what i needed for a true or false thing.

Comment: `slcnt == "Y"` is what gets evaluated to `True` or `False`.

Comment: You could also do `slcnt = input("Would you like to slow count? Y/N: ") == "Y"` (that would be the correct way to make `slcnt` into a bool value in this context), and then `if slcnt:` instead of `if slcnt == "Y"`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is this line `slcnt = bool(input("Would you like to slow count? Y/N: "))`, you can't make it boolean because you are asking for a character. It may be fixed like this:

```py
import time

def cnt(start, end):
    for x in range(start, end+1):
        print(x)
        time.sleep(1)
    print("Done!")

def count():
    num = int(input("Enter a number to count to: "))
    #Slow count meaning counting 1 by 1 in console.
    slcnt = input("Would you like to slow count? Y/N: ").upper()
    if slcnt == "Y":
        cnt(0, num)
    elif slcnt == "N":
        for i in range(num):
            print(i)
        print("Done")

count()
```

You didn't add the line `import time`, but I guess it was a mistake when you pasted the code.
I also added `upper()` to the input function, so the script will accept Y/N and y/n.

Comment: Yeah, forgot about that, sorry.